Run livewire click method based on whether checkbox is checked or not
I'm new to livewire.
And I have Livewire component like below


<label for="active">Active:</label>



<input type="checkbox" id="active" wire:model.live="active" >Active

And component class have below code
class Advices extends Component
{
    public $advices, $text, $priority, $attached_day, $active, $advice_id;
    public $updateMode = false;
    public function render()
    {
        $this->advices = Advice::all();
        return view('livewire.advices');
    }
    private function resetInputFields(){
        $this->text='';
        $this->priority='';
        $this->attached_day='';
        $this->active='';
    }
    public function store()
    {
        $validator=$this->validate([
            'text'=>'bail|required',
            'priority'=>'nullable|integer',
            'attached_day'=>'nullable|integer|max:99',
            'active'=>'boolean'
        ]);
        $advice= new Advice();
        $advice->text= $this->text;
        $advice->priority= $this->priority ?? 1;
        $advice->attached_day = $this->attached_day ?? null;
        $advice->active= $this->active ?? true;
        $advice->timestamps = false;
        $advice->save();
        session()->flash('message','Advice Created Successfully.');
        $this->resetInputFields();
    }
    }

my requirements are that when the checkbox is clicked, the true value is sent, and when not clicked, the false value is sent
I meant that if the checkbox is checked, then "active"=true, if the checkbox is not checked, then "active"=false.
I don't want to use JS, so if you can give me a solution without JS I will be very happy.

The $active property must be a boolean (it's also validated as boolean in your code)
So, the variable must be initialized as boolean, let's say true:
public $active = true;

then when you reset it, you must assign to it a boolean value not an empty string:

private function resetInputFields()
{
    .....

    $this->active = true;
}

Additional informations
Initializing to true is just one example.
If necessary, you can initialize the value to false instead.
If you have an initial value read from a persistent storage (like a DB) you can initialize the variable in the mount() method which acts like a __construct() (see here for details).
For example:
public function mount()
{
    $data = MyModel::first();
    .....
    $this->active = $data->active;
    .....
}

and probably you need to add a cast in your model:
protected $casts = [
   'active' => 'boolean',
];


Also, if you need, you can set the variable to false in the resetInputFields() method:
private function resetInputFields(){
     $this->active = false;
}


And then how do I assign the "active" value to 'false' if the checkbox is unchecked?

The value is set to false by the frontend when you uncheck  the checkbox

Thanks, but I'm wondering how to make the value 'active'="false" in case the checkbox was not touched at all. For example, all fields except 'active' are filled in (the checkbox is not touched) and sent for addition, and as a result, the fields of the filled values are added, and the value of 'active' is equated to "false".

Ok, see the addtional informations added in my answer
